# Can I connect circuits for a dishwasher and sink disposal unit to the same breaker?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

Can the garbage disposal and dishwasher, each with its own GFCI receptacle, share the same 20 amp circuit at the main electrical panel?

[image]

Comment: Depends. What are the requirements of your disposal and dishwasher?

Comment: If they can share, then you may want to consider wiring dishwasher (regular receptacle) to disposal (GFCI) to panel, or use regular receptacles for both and use a GFCI breaker. No need for two separate GFCI receptacles.

Comment: Yes, what are the nameplate ratings for your dishwasher and disposal?

Comment: That panel is crazy small. Is it a subpanel?  If not is it too late to fit a larger one?  Reason I ask is, if that's your only panel, you'll be quickly forced to use double-stuffed breakers, and those don't come in GFCI or AFCI. Which is a problem!

Comment: Panel is 200 amp.

Comment: @Harper is concerned about the number of spaces the panel has for breakers, not amperage. If I'm seeing it right, the main breaker is in the upper left, with 16 total slots below, 8 of which are used in your picture. Iirc, my kitchen alone has 11 circuits (including separate dish washer and disposal) which doesn't leave much for the rest of the house. A 40 space panel can be had for not much more than that 16 space one. Some even come with some breakers as a package. It's well worth the extra $$ now to save trouble adding circuits (and AFCI & GFCI breakers) later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is kind of a tricky question. For many years contractors connected the disposal and dishwasher on a split receptacle below the sink. Now with newer and larger appliances consuming more power there could be a problem.

Also there has been some conversations in the AHJ and Code communities about NEC 400.12 (2) *Uses not permitted - Where running through holes in walls ...* Does it mean a fixed appliance electrical cords passing through a cabinet wall? Right now it's kind of up in the air and I'm betting there will be a code clarification coming up in newer revisions.

If you can perhaps the smarter move would be to extend the circuit from the disposal receptacle and install a separate receptacle behind the dishwasher. Or super safe install a separate circuit for each appliance.

One last thing, both now need to be on GFCI protected circuits.

So make sure your GFCI protected, verify the circuit can hold the total load (that includes the start up surge of motors) using the nameplate data of the appliances and take it from there.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Outstanding,  Thank you for taking the time to share your knowledge!